# warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Tags: c

I wrote the following code:

```
void buildArrays(char *pLastLetter[],int length[], int size, const char str[]) {

    int i;
    int strIndex = 0;
    int letterCounter = 0;

    for (i=0; i<size; i++) {

        while ( (str[strIndex] != SEPERATOR) || (str[strIndex] != '\0') ) {
            letterCounter++;
            strIndex++;
        }
        pLastLetter[i] = &str[strIndex-1];
        length[i] = letterCounter;
        letterCounter = 0;
        strIndex++;
    }
}
```

and I'm getting the above warning on `pLastLetter[i] = &str[strIndex-1];`

> `pLastLetter is a pointers array that points to a char in str[].`

Anyone knows why I'm getting it and how to fix it?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Well, as you said yourself, `pLastLetter` is an array of `char *` pointers, while `str` is an array of `const char`. The `&str[strIndex-1]` expression has type `const char*`. You are not allowed to assign a `const char*` value to a `char *` pointer. That would violate the rules of const-correctness. In fact, what you are doing is an error in C. C compilers traditionally report it as a mere "warning" to avoid breaking some old legacy code.

As for "how to fix it"... It depends on what you are trying to do. Either make `pLastLetter` an array of `const char*` or remove the `const` from `str`.

Comment: thank you very much for the quick answer, which brings me to another quetion: if this is the function:
void buildArrays(char *pLastLetter[],int length[], int size, const char str[]) 
is it ok to call to this function by:
buildArrays(pLastLetter[],length,str) where str is of type char* and not const char*?
compiler does not output a warning, however can it cause an undefined behaviour?

thank you

Comment: @Asher: `const T*` is just a promise not to modify the pointee through that pointer, so you can implicitly convert a `T*` to `const T*` fine. (This does fall down for pointers-to-pointers, though.  See http://c-faq.com/ansi/constmismatch.html .)

Answer (score 7):

str is const, pLastLetter isn't.  It's saying the const qualifier is discarded if you do this.

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering what qualifiers it was saying would be discarded.