# Why was I able to change the value of a const int here?

Tags: c, pointers

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    const int x = 10;
    int *p;
    p=&x;
    *p=20;
    printf("Value at p: %d \n",*p);
    printf("Value at x: %d", x);
}
```

The output I get is:

> Value at p: 20
>   Value at x: 20

Thus, the value of a constant variable is changed. Is this one of the disadvantages of using pointers?

Comment: C doesn't prevent you from doing dumb things like this. You do get a warning from the compiler though: `const.c:9: warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type`

Comment: `#include "stdio.h"` => `#include <stdio.h>`

Comment: Note that depending on the compiler and optimizations enabled, you could get have in your output "Value at x: 10".

Comment: The only useful `const` in C that I can see is in parameters.

Answer (score 2):

You used a `int*` to point to a `const` int. you should get:

```
 error: invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int*’
```

when you do:

```
p = &x;
```

You probably needs to update your compiler, a decent compiler should have told you this error or at least gave you warning about this.

Comment: But he didn't, because he is using a bad compiler, I guess.

Comment: @Elazar I guess so. Or may be old versioned compilers

Comment: I use gcc! I thought gcc was good enough!

Comment: @user2350631 I use gcc too, what version is that?

Comment: @user2350631 gcc 4.7.3 report the error.

Comment: the version is 4.5.3!

Comment: @user2350631 then it is weird, since I am also using gcc 4.5.3 but reported the error

Comment: @user2350631 Did you disable warnings?

Comment: Or, @user2350631: are you reviewing the warnings? Many developers assume that if it compiles, it's good.

Comment: Oh yes! I am receiving a warning!

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following error message:

`error: invalid conversion from ‘const int*’ to ‘int*’`

`const int`, `int const`, `const int *`, `int const *`, please see this post: [const int = int const?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3247285/const-int-int-const)

It's just how you use it.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are using the C language in the wrong way and the compiler let you compile this code while giving only a warning

```
warning: assignment discards ‘const’ qualifier from pointer target type [enabled by default]
```

And there are answers for that on SO, such as [warning: assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479770/warning-assignment-discards-qualifiers-from-pointer-target-type)

Answer (score 0):

Any decent compiler will tell you that you are discarding the const qualifier.

C assumes that the programmer is always right, hence it's your choice to ignore your compiler's warnings or not. As usual, this is not a disadvantage as long as you know what you're doing!

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have noted, writing a program to try to modify a `const` qualified variable like this results in a program that has *undefined behaviour*.  This means that your program can do anything at all - as an example of this, when I compile your program with optimisations enabled, I see this output:

```
Value at p: 20
Value at x: 10
```

..and if I add the `static` qualifier to the variable `x` then the program crashes at runtime.