# warning: "assignment discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type"

Tags: c, strtod

I made my own `strtod()` function.

I can `printf` in console but it is giving warning like this when it runs:

> myStrTod.c|29|warning: "assignment discards 'const' qualifier from
>   pointer target type"|

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
float myStrTod(const char * nPtr, char ** endPtr);
int rakamMi(int c);

int main()
{
    float d;
    const char *string = "51.2% kabul edildi";
    char *stringPtr;

    d = myStrTod(string,&stringPtr);
    printf("%.3f %s\n",d,stringPtr);
    return 0;
}

float myStrTod(const char * nPtr, char ** endPtr)
{
    char s1[20],s2[50];
    int i,j,k = 0,pnt,y = 1,num1 = 0,num2= 0;
    float f1,f2;
    for(i = 0; nPtr[i]; i++){
        if(rakamMi(nPtr[i]) || nPtr[i] == '.')
            s1[i] = nPtr[i];
        else break;
    }
    j = i;
    for(; nPtr[i]; i++)
       endPtr[i - j] = nPtr + i;

    for(i = 0; s1[i]; i++)
        if(s1[i] == '.'){
            pnt = i;
            break;
        }

    for (i = 0; s1[i]; i++)
    {
        if(i < pnt) num1 = num1 * 10 + (s1[i] - 48);
        else if (i == pnt) continue;
        else{
            num2 = num2 * 10 + (s1[i] - 48);
            ++k;
        }
    }
    for(i = 1; i <= k; i++)
        y = y * 10;

    f1 = num2 / (float) y;
    f2 = num1 + f1;
   // endPtr = s2;
    return f2;
}

int rakamMi(int c)
{
    if(c >= 48 && c <= 57)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please post the entire error/warning message(s) from the compiler.

Comment: C'mon people, at least try.  Do you have no access to a search engine at your location?  This is the first result from your error message : (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479770/warning-assignment-discards-qualifiers-from-pointer-target-type)

Comment: it's not the answer. I worried about that but when i changed const char to char it still give an error.

Comment: you should say what the new error is, obviously.

Comment: It's a runtime error, not a build error.

Comment: Program given the result but after that program.exe has stopped working!

Comment: `endPtr[i - j] = nPtr + i;` => When endPtr (aka `stringPtr`) is initialised?

Comment: What does endPtr in myStrTod point to? Is that an element of an array? What's the  size?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign a value of type pointer-to-const-char to a variable of type pointer-to-char.  You could change the signature of `myStrTod` so that your output is to a pointer to const char:

```
float myStrTod(const char *nPtr, const char **endPtr);
```

Then GCC will report a different error:

```
40937624.c: In function ‘main’:
40937624.c:11:25: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘myStrTod’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     d = myStrTod(string,&stringPtr);
                         ^
40937624.c:2:7: note: expected ‘const char **’ but argument is of type ‘char **’
```

This can be fixed by declaring `stringPtr` as pointer to const:

```
const char *stringPtr;
```

Since you never write to the content of `*stringPtr`, this is then sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

> Program given the result but after that program.exe has stopped working!

The reason for that is this:

```
    j = i;
    for(; nPtr[i]; i++)
       endPtr[i - j] = nPtr + i;
```

You're passing the address of just a single `char *stringPtr` to the function, but use the parameter `endPtr` as if there were an array of `char *`, thereby overwriting memory behind the storage of `stringPtr`. Change all the above to:

```
    *endPtr = nPtr + i;
```